# how can i generate stepdefintion file from feature file in protractor (looking for something like specflow)

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

Have tried "cucumber gherkin full support" extension, but it gives option to navigate to a step not to generate step". Is there any way i can generate step definition from feature file directly?

enter image description here
**strong text**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbOqp.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have not implemented your step definitions, Cucumber will warn you asking to create them with the template.

You can copy paste them and implement your logic inside it.

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: After writing feature files, try to run the tests. If the step definitions are not in place already, cucumber will warn you asking to create the respective step with the template

Comment: when i run npm test, nothing happens, i have attached package.json, launch.json and tsconfig.json, could you please point out the mistake i am doing here?

Comment: Can you upload your project in github and share the repo URL? I can check the issue

Comment: I don't see your feature files and steps folder. Your test folder is not available

Answer (score 0):

To generate the steps instead of running it through protractor you can add another command to in your scripts like 
"cuke-test": "cucumber-js -r outputjs/pathtoyourstepdeffolder/*.js", and give it a dry run. It should give you the snippets for the unimplemented steps. The tidy gherkin extension in chrome is quite good too.